# Join values into one line with specific separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Noob here...
I'm trying to develop a handful of python tools in my new role. I'm not a developer, but want/need to learn some handy coding.

Background:
Sometimes we're provided with a CSV and some populated columns. The values of one of these columns are reference IDs that we will need to perform DB searches on. Sometimes there can be a handful or thousands even millions of rows. We will manually copy the required column into a text editor such as Sublime, remove all line breaks, and insert a separator of ',' between each value and an ' at the beginning and end of the line.  We do this so it can be copied into a SQL SELECT IN statement (if you work on DB, you'll be familiar with this).
The above requires manual work when it could be done with code.

As with some other python tools I'm working on, they're all centred around Pandas, so I would like this tool to use them, although I am open to other suggestions.

Solution:
I have knocked together the below. It takes a CSV and loads it into a dataframe. I use argparse to select the CSV and the column I want to extract and work on. The required column is extracted to a variable where I replace line endings with ','. This pretty much works as expected apart from the beginning and end of the line, the beginning is missing a ', and the end has an additional ,'
Example:
Beginning: 1011l792873442','1011l792873443','1100l789586969'
End: '1100l786697395','1100l786697396','1100l786697397','

I'd like to know...

1. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. How do I address the missing ' at the beginning of the line and the additional,' at the end?

Edit:
Source format:
Sorry, I couldn't get this to format correctly in the post.
campaign_id,conversion_item_id,status
1100l327,1011l792873442,rejected
1100l327,1011l792873443,rejected
1100l327,1100l789586969,approved
1100l327,1100l789586970,rejected

Required output:
(conversioon_item)
'1011l792873442','1011l792873443','1100l789586969','1100l789586970'

Constructive criticism is welcome.

Thanks,

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="Source file")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output file")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--name", help="Provide the column name to format")
args = parser.parse_args()

df = pd.read_csv(args.input, usecols=[args.name])
df.to_csv(args.output, index=False, header=False)

# Read in the file
filename = (args.output)
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace("\n", "','")

# Write the file out again
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
    print(filedata)
```

Comment: Hello, can you put an example of the format read and the expected result after process ?

Comment: Updated post with source and output format.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new string and assign it to your current string with comma's at the beginning and end like this:

Replace the target string

```
filedata = filedata.replace("\n", "','")

newfiledata = "," + filedata + ","

print(newfiledata)
```

Note: If you use this approach, every time you now mention filedata after this change, you should now be calling newfiledata as it represents your most recent changes to the variable filedata

If you don't want to create a new instance you can just do:

```
filedata = "," + filedata + ","
```

I think it's good practice to create a new instance however just because it makes it easier to go back to the original if you need to for whatever reason.

Comment: This is pretty much there.  I think my initial replace is causing the end-of-line issue in that there is an extra ;' at the end.

'1100l786697397','

Comment: Yeah so you can change your initial replace from 


filedata = filedata.replace("\n", "','") to filedata = filedata.replace(" ", "','")

This way you're adding comments between spaces and not just every new line

Comment: I made the change but it doesn't join the values into one line anymore with the output being the same as the input.